# Python - RegEx match does not write to file if it contains full-stop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to use a RegEx expression in a Python script in order to find specific variables within a webpage. I then export this using a csv file. However, if the found group contains a full-stop, it does not export at all. How do I remedy this?

In this webpage, the item displayed changes depending on a code inputted. My script automates the inputting of codes, and then records the item produced. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
import re

regName = r'The item name is (.*?)\.'

response = opener.open(
    'http://website.com/webpage.php' + itemValues)
html = response.read()
responseDecode = html.decode('utf8')

name = re.findall(regName, responseDecode)

#Convert stuff to Unicode
uniName = name[0].encode('utf8', 'replace')

with open("readable.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write("\n"*2)
    file.write(uniName + '\n')
```

Of note, I convert to unicode because some of the item names contain accented characters.

EDIT: an example of something that would not work would be, for instance, R.O.B.O.T . All that would be written would be R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `regName = r'The item name is (.*?)\.$'` The `$` marks the end of the string, which would allow the other full stops to not be consumed early. Right now the regular expression is being greedy and matching on the first one.

Or if the string doesn't end right there, try adding a space or some other following character. You need to specify the kind of character that marks the end of the item string.